# Automorphisms of algebraic groups and maximal tori

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over a field $k$, and $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus. Assume that $f$ is an automorphism of $G$ *as an abstract group*. Is it true that $f$ maps $T$ to some maximal torus?

Comment: Since you did not specify $k$ to be algebraically closed, just to be sure, what is your definition of a linear algebraic group?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain You can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For semisimple complex algebraic groups all automorphisms are compositions of algebraic automorphisms and elements of $Gal({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb Q})$. The question then essentially reduces to the solvable case. Consider, however, ${\mathbb C}\times {\mathbb C}^*\cong {\mathbb R}^2 \times ({\mathbb R}_+\times U(1))$. Each factor contains a subgroup isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$ (it is the multiplicative group ${\mathbb R}_+$ for the second factor). Now, you can swap them using this isomorphism and thereby destroy the maximal split torus (I think this is what you had in mind).